# Wi-Fi password got changed by parents and I can’t access it

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, iphone

I have an iPhone 6 and my parents changed my Wi-Fi password. I’m not connected to Wi-Fi and I don’t know how to access my password. Me being the dumb person I am I didn’t turn on my keychain acess. Someone please help me.

Comment: You have to ask what the password is. Only practical way.

Comment: Avoiding an assumption of this being punitive, but did your parents just change it and forgot to tell you? Or I’d something else up? Regardless the one ones who can help you deal with this are your parents themselves. Nobody else.

Comment: Have you been naughty? Did they also put coal in your socks?

Comment: There is indeed a way to reset the wifi password. The prerequisite for obtaining the method is that please let us know why your parents reset the password. Or did they forget the password?

Comment: You can buy a cheap mini router for about $20. Plug it to your home router via cable. (Maybe you need to hide it). Then you just connect to your own WiFi. No one can stop your from accessing the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask them for the password

Answer (score 1):

You could do a hard reset of the Wifi Router, then make a new password on it....but then everyone else would get disconnected and you'd probably get in trouble.  LOL.

Comment: I don't think this is good advice for a router that does not belong to the person asking the question

Comment: I did write the consequences.... which eludes it’s a bad idea.